# How do I create working assertion versus JSON structure in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, web-api-testing

I`m performing API automation testing and use GET request via Cypress and receive in the body the next structure:

```
{
my_list: [
{
code: "SAT-12-33-1",
description: "FLOOR 1",
payment: "128"
},
{
code: "SAT-12-33-2",
description: "FLOOR 2",
payment: "33"
},
{
code: "SAT-12-33-3",
description: "FLOOR 3",
payment: "311"
},
{
code: "SAT-12-33-4",
description: "FLOOR 4",
payment: "342"
},
{
....and so on. The full structure is 3400 records.
Could somebody give me an exact example, HOW to validate, that for instance this chunk (2 elements only) of code:
{
code: "SAT-12-33-2",
description: "FLOOR 2",
payment: "33"
},
{
code: "SAT-12-33-3",
description: "FLOOR 3",
payment: "311"
}
```

exactly matching on the received array of 3400 records. In my case, I will have 3 or 4 elements and I have to compare them/validate versus the big array.
I have tried expect(response.body).to.contain(), deep.equal(), .should('include') and more, but does not work to me.
Can someone provide the exact code that matching part of the structure above to the whole request body with the same structure? Again, I will have 2 or 3 elements and want to compare them together to a big array of 3400 elements?
Thank you very much!